# Create a custom shape in container flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanna try and create the following design for the tab bar option as a container.

Desired container style

[image]

The closest i got is with this code snippet

```
class AngledContainerClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final borderRadius = 5 * size.shortestSide;
    final path = Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width - 60, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width - 16, size.height);
    path.lineTo(16, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And use it like this

```
ClipPath(
      clipper: AngledContainerClipper(),
      child: Container(
        height: 72,
          child: Tab(text: 'Tab1'),
      ),
    ),
```

I've tried different things but couldnt crack this yet. will be helpful if anyone can provide me with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
class GSCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Layer 1

    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = size.width * 0.00
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt
      ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.miter;

    Path path = Path();
    double radius = size.height * 0.25;

    path.moveTo(0, radius);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.75, 0);
    path.lineTo(radius, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, 0, radius);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    Paint stroke = Paint()
      ..color = const Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = size.width * 0.00
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt
      ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.miter;

    canvas.drawPath(path, stroke);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Use it like this

```
CustomPaint(
        size: Size(500, (500 * 0.5).toDouble()),
        // 500 is WIDTH, You can Replace with your desired width for Custom Paint and height will be calculated automatically
        painter: GSCustomPainter(),
        child: const SizedBox(height: 300, width: 500, child: Center(child: Text('Child Widget'))),
      ),
```

My output

[image]

Comment: thank you for the kind input. i was able to et something like this too previously, but was always failed to get the corner rounded at top right of this custom container.